# How to use multiple features such as pitch, formants, shimmer and jitter to train HMM using HTK toolkit instead of MFCC only?

Tags: speech-recognition, speech-to-text, speech

I am trying to develop a note transcription system using HMM. For this I am using HTK Toolkit. I want to use different features such as pitch, formants, shimmer and jitter instead of MFCC only.

How can I create a feature vector of above features to train HMM in HTK so that I can improve the performance of the system?

Answer (score 1):

This issue has been covered many times on HTK forums and mailing list, you can search for more details.

Basically you need to create your features first for every frame in some form, for example in text table. Then you can convert those values to a binary HTK format using C code or Matlab code. C code is not very complex but it requires you an understanding of HTK binary format. For example you can check detailed code at:

http://blog.jamesrossiter.co.uk/2008/11/16/converting-csv-and-vector-data-to-native-htk-format-using-c/

http://www.ee.ic.ac.uk/hp/staff/dmb/voicebox/doc/voicebox/writehtk.html

Comment: I have idea about it. But in a case of training how the config or wave_config file is defined (specifically the TARGETKIND = ? in case of multiple features e.g pitch, formants).

Comment: TARGETKIND=USER, inside there could be anything.

Comment: I have computed the feature file for one feature (without extension) and try to use HCompV -A -D -T 1 -C config -f 0.01 -m -S train.scp -M hmm0 proto. It gives error ERROR [+6310]  OpenParmChannel: cannot open Parm File path/c_01. Is there a problem with proto or binary file extension.

Comment: Right, proto file must also have targetkind USER

Comment: It should be a problem with train.scp then which lists the files. Do you really have that file both in train.scp and on filesystem?

Comment: I have figured it out. Now it gives error  Vector size in /path/c_01[261] is incompatible with hmm proto[1] my proto start line is ~o <VecSize> 1 <USER> and config contain            TARGETKIND = USER
TARGETRATE = 125000.0
WINDOWSIZE = 500000.0  I kept 5 states, mean and variance field contain 1 element as feature vector is 1. what could be the soln for that.

Comment: Looks like your binary file c_01 has vector size 261, it means you incorrectly created it. Make sure that feature file has 1 vector, check header with HList. Make sure you generated it properly.

Comment: WARNING [-7324]  StepBack: File /path/ml_08 - bad data or over pruning in HERest. I tried to set higher values in -t option. Still it gives same warning.